# How to adapt a JS sidebar in Angular?

Tags: angular

I really like this sidebar, the problem is that it is in JS (link below).

https://codepen.io/rametta/pen/EWgORr

The code has changed is the following:

```
const $menu = $('#burger');
const $sidebar = $('.sidebar');
const $sidebarItemTitles = $('.sidebar-item-title');

let isOpen = true;

$menu.on('click', () => {
    if(isOpen) {
        $sidebarItemTitles.addClass('hide');
        $sidebar.removeClass('expanded');
    } else {
        $sidebarItemTitles.removeClass('hide');
        $sidebar.addClass('expanded');
    }
    isOpen = !isOpen
})
```

Does anyone know how i can adapt this in angular?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-n1wun8?file=src/app/admin/admin.component.ts

I'm still too beginner to know how to do it alone.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular you can bind conditional style classes with the `[ngClass]` attribute, more info [here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass).

So in your case you want to bind the style classes `hide` and `expanded` based on the value of `isOpen`.

```
<div class="sidebar" [ngClass]="{'expanded': isOpen, 'hide': !isOpen}">
```

Now if `isOpen` is true the sidebar will have the style class 'expanded' and otherwise if it's false the style class 'hide'.

Updated [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vkukdy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fadmin%2Fadmin.component.html)